# Apache rewrite rules query having regular expression and runs recursively

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, recursion, httpserver

I am new to apache rewrite rules.
I am trying to rewrite a URL

For ex :

http://www.example.com/try/this/all+letters+with+plus -> http://www.example.com/try/this/allletterswithplus

so the requirement is I have to redirect it to URL having /try/this and the rest excluding + sign. One point to note, the number of plus sign is not fixed, it can have 2 to 7 or may be more plus signs. Preferably, an option with regex will be good because the **all+letters+with+plus** text can include anything from number to alphabets but no signs

I tried some combination, but then it went into recursive loop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in 2 steps using mod_rewrite. The first step is to remove all of the "+" from anything after `/try/this/`, then the second step is to check if the request originally had "+" but the current URI doesn't.

This rule will keep removing "+" signs until there aren't any. But we're just passing this through the rewrite engine.

```
RewriteRule ^try/this/(.*)\+(.*)$ /try/this/$1$2 [PT]
```

This rule checks if the original request had a URL with "+" in it, and if it does, check to see if they've all been removed. If so, end all the rewriting and redirect the browser:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /try/this/.*\+.*\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^try/this/([^\+]*)$ /try/this/$1 [R,L]
```

You mentioned that you wanted to redirect to the /try/this/ URL without the "+" signs. But if you just want to rewrite it internally and not redirect the browser, you don't need the 2nd part, just the first rule will remove them.

Comment: Hi Jon,
This does not seem to work. It only removed the + plus sign from the last two letter. I want this to work recursively removing all the plus sign.
http://www.example.com/try/this/all+letters+with+plus -> http://www.example.com/try/this/all+letters+withplus

You were correct, I just want it to rewrite internally not redirecting this to different URL.

Any suggetions.

Thanks. I find some lead in this direction with your suggestions.

Comment: If you don't need redirect, then just use the top rule. When I enter `RewriteRule ^try/this/(.*)\+(.*)$ /try/this/$1$2 [PT]` in my .htaccess file, and tested with "example.com/try/this/a+b+c+d+++++e++++f++++++g+h+++++", I see a request for "example.com/try/this/abcdefgh" in the logs.